# TCP channel of Deleporter remoting service closes prematurely

Tags: .net, selenium, remoting

We have a UI test suite for our ASP.NET MVC3 website. We are using Selenium and IIS Express during tests. The IIS Express is started before the first test and shutdown after the last test.

Because our system has some external dependencies, which are however irrelevant for testing the UI we have been trying to use Deleporter for mocking those dependencies. The Deleporter configuration is usually done at the beginning of each test, and it works just fine, for a while. But then after some tests have been executed the Deleporter service in IIS express process stops working and the client cannot reach it anymore. After that all subsequent tests fail. Sometimesthe whole test suite is also executed successfully.

Looking at the allocated ports with TCPView shows that when the Deleporter service stops responding the TCP channel on the configured port has in fact disappeared from the IIS Express process. Any idea why this happens? Depending on the used browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE), each test can take up 45 seconds to run, so there might be around 30+ seconds between calls to the Deleporter service.

Looking at the Deleporter code, I can see that the Deleporter service is implemented so that it returns null for the InitializeLifeTimeServices method and it is registered as a Singleton service.